# VB6 How to disable weekend days from Calendar control

Tags: date, vb6, calendar, set

I'm almost finishing my VB6 app and I'm trying to add some visual enhancements to controls. 
My app allows to assign medical shifts to patients for which I use a Calendar Control. Now, I'm trying to find a way to disable Saturday and Sundays from being selected. Besides, it would be great if I could change the color of days if there are available shifts on them (that will be based on a sql query).

Does anyone know if this is feasible? I have looked at so many web pages for help but no success.
Thanks for your help

Gerardo

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely not.  The control is not even a standard Windows control, which means you're limited by the original implementation of it when Microsoft made it for VB6 back many years ago.

The easiest solution is to produce an error, or cause the cursor to switch to a different, nearby date.

The best solution is to make your own control, which would not be such a bad idea if you want anymore flexibility.

Comment: The Calendar control has licensing and redist issues for VB6 programs anyway.  It became part of MS Access.

Comment: Kal at http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?657911-VB6-MSCAL-OCX-Replacement-quot-Kal-quot is an open source 100% VB6 Calendar-like control that might server as the basis of a customized Calendar.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll try. The disadvantage is that I have too many code already written and deadline is quite near.
I ll take a look at it.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

You could redesign your form to have a grid that shows appointment times, by staff. Just shade the squares according to availability.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good option too. The only problem is that I'm running out of time, I'll think about. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Weekday(date)` or `WeekdayName(date)` function to see if the user entered a date that corresponds to a weekend day.